# Creating a symbolic link using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, symlink

I am struggling with a bit of PowerShell, which I feel I should be able to do easily, and would appreciate some help.

I have a series of paths storing log and config files within `C:\temp`. Not only that, but I need to delete the temp file and then create a symbolic link to the logged on user's OneDrive every time they run the app (which is launched with a batch file).

So I need it to run through about 10 folders such as

```
rmdir /Q /S c:\temp\app\cgi-bin
rmdir /Q /S c:\temp\app\contrib
rmdir /Q /S c:\temp\app\logs 

etc.
```

...and then run the equivalent of:

```
mklink /D c:\temp\app\cgi-bin c:\users\<logged on user>\One Drive - Company Name\app\cgi-bin
mklink /D c:\temp\app\contrib c:\users\<logged on user>\One Drive - Company Name\app\contrib
mklink /D c:\temp\app\logs c:\users\<logged on user>\One Drive - Company Name\app\logs
```

What I have attempted in PS to do this is below:

```
$username = $env:username

(get-item C:\temp\app\cgi-bin).Delete()
New-item -ItemType SymbolicLink -path c:\temp\app\cgi-bin -target 'C:\users\$username\OneDrive - Company Name\app\cgi-bin\'
```

...and then was going to get it to run the same for each location:

```
$username = $env:username

(get-item C:\temp\app\contrib).Delete()
New-item -ItemType SymbolicLink -path c:\temp\app\contrib -target 'C:\users\$username\OneDrive - Company Name\app\contrib\'

etc.
```

...but have got completely lost. I feel there should be an easy way to loop through the original folder locations and then joining the parts together. I had another go with `join-path`, but it didn't go too well either:

```
New-item -ItemType SymbolicLink -path C:\temp\app\cgi-bin -target (join-path 'C:\users' '"OneDrive - Company Name\app\cgi-bin\"')
```

Comment: BTW, rather than guessing that the end user has their OneDrive location in a directory within a hard coded 'profile' directory, you should probably be using the appropriate variable. Examples: ```$onedrivepath = $env:onedrivecommercial```, ```$onedrivepath = $env:onedriveconsumer```, or ```$onedrivepath = $env:onedrive```.

Comment: @Qwerty: Did some conversation get deleted? OP is asking for help with a Symbolic link, and your code is creating a shortcut(.lnk file). They're not the same thing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just, first, as you're new here -- so Welcome ! --, it doesn't really matter, but keep in mind to post the errors you are getting, because I had to figure them out here .

Right, just a few things first :

- to loop through an array, you can use the `foreach(){}` method.
- as @Compo stated, you can use `$env:onedrive` to get the current user's OneDrive directory (`$env` is the *environment variable*, it's a preset system-wide variable basically containing user-useful settings)
- you cannot create a symbolic link pointing to a non-existing directory, so here, if the folders in OneDrive don't exist, it won't work; so I'm adding a line here to check if the folder exists, and create it if not, just make sure `app` exists !

```
$onedrive = "$env:onedrive - Company Name"
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\app").Name){
    Remove-Item -Path $folder
    $onedrivePath = "$onedrive\app\$folder"
    if (-not(Test-Path $onedrivePath)){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $onedrivePath
    }
    New-item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "c:\temp\app\$folder" -target $onedrivePath
}
```

Feel free to comment if you want more explanations, and have a wonderful PowerShell journey (PowerShell is one of those incredible but underestimated languages...)

Silloky

EDIT :

After modifications to the script as you requested, here it is in all its beauty !

```
$onedrive = "$env:onedrive"
$pathArray = @(
    "contrib", 
    "htdocs", 
    "install", 
    "licenses", 
    "locale", 
    "apache\logs", 
    "mysql\data", 
    "mysql\backup", 
    "perl", 
    "php", 
    "phpMyAdmin", 
    "sendmail", 
    "tmp", 
    "tomcat", 
    "webdav"
)

foreach ($path in $pathArray) {
    $localpath = "c:\app\$path"
    if (Test-Path $localpath) {
        Remove-Item -path $localpath -Recurse -force -Confirm:$false
    }
    # Write-Output "Setting OneDrive Path"
    $onedrivePath = "$onedrive\app\$path"
    if (-not(Test-Path $onedrivePath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $onedrivePath
    }
    # Write-Output "Creating Junction"
    New-item -ItemType Junction -Path "$localpath" -target $onedrivePath
}
```

I replaced `Read-Host` by `Write-Output` as it is more adequate : `Read-Host` prompts for user input (like `input()` in Python) when `Write-Output` prints to the console (like `print()` in Python), which is what you want assuming from the "prompt" texts.

I've also organised the array in much more semantic way, making it easier to edit.

Silloky

Comment: WOW thank you so much for all the help. It does make more sense now! @compo I can see me using those variables a lot of the coming years and thought there would be a nice way to loop through. Been in IT a long time but feel like a n00b with scripting and coding so all the help is much appreciated.

Comment: thats a nice look script and really appreciate your time, an upvote doesn't seem enough appeciation there needs to be a tip jar to buy you a pint!

made a few tweaks to the script and almost there, the $env:onedrive includes the company name so i have shortened the first bit. One problem is that it bring back files as well so need to figure out why. Also its my fault i didn't describe it well enough i only need to go througha pre-defined list of folders i know contain either log or config files for this app. Will keep me busy this week :)

Thanks again, will mark as answered when i finish

Comment: @ChrisMont as I understand, you only want loop through a certain list of folders ? you would want to use an array for that... would you like me to edit my answer ? cheers

Comment: @ChrisMont feel free to join the PowerShell discord server and ping "@Silloky", it will be easier to follow a thread than stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for your help, its been a mad week but I have now managed to figure it out and its working which is great. Thanks again everyone especially @silloky for taking time to help. I will post the full code in the Answer if it helps anyone else

Comment: No problem, but submitting your own answer isn't considered a good practice on Stack Exchange, so I am going to edit my answer with your code (improving it slightly probably...).

Comment: If this script works (it should ), would you mind accepting my answer please (you mentioned a pint of beer, but I think I would prefer that as of my age lol).

Comment: haha sorry and thanks i have accepted your answer. thanks again for the help and if you have a tip jar i will buy you a milkshake instead of a beer then !

Answer (score 0):

```
$onedrive = "$env:onedrive"
$pathvariable = @("contrib", "htdocs", "install", "licenses", "locale", "apache\logs", "mysql\data", "mysql\backup", "perl", "php", "phpMyAdmin", "sendmail", "tmp", "tomcat", "webdav")

foreach ($var in $pathvariable) {
$localpath = "c:\app\$var"
         
   if (Test-Path $localpath){
        
Remove-Item -path $localpath -Recurse -force -Confirm:$false
    }

##Read-Host -Prompt "Setting OneDrive Path"
$onedrivePath = "$onedrive\app\$var"

    if (-not(Test-Path $onedrivePath)){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $onedrivePath
    }

##Read-Host -Prompt "Creating Junction"

    New-item -ItemType Junction -Path "$localpath" -target $onedrivePath
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).